# Sequelize: Before Create Hook is Not Working As Intended

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to perform a beforeCreate operation on a model that I created via Sequelize. I'm trying to have the password and salt saved before creating the user. However, the user is created without the encrypted password or salt. I'm not too familiar with Node.JS but I'm assuming this has to do with it's asynchronous nature. Any idea how to properly introduce a callback so that my create function behaves as intended?

Model:

```js
'use strict';
var Promise = require("bluebird"); 
var bcrypt =Promise.promisifyAll(require("bcrypt-nodejs"));
const SALT_ROUNDS = 10; 

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false, validate: { notEmpty: true } }, 
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false, isEmail: true },
    phone_number: DataTypes.STRING,
    password_hash: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true, validate: { notEmpty: true } }, 
    password_salt: DataTypes.STRING,
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    user_type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    two_factor_enabled: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false, },
    email_verified: DataTypes.DATE,
    active: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: true, },
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      },
      validPassword: function(password, passwd, callback) {
        bcrypt.compare(password, passwd, function(err, isMatch) {
          if (isMatch) {
            return callback(null, true);
          } else {
            return callback(null, false); 
          }
        });
      },
    },
    hooks: {
 beforeCreate: function(user, {}) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_ROUNDS, function(err, salt) {
   bcrypt.hash(user.password_hash, salt, function(){}, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) {
     return sequelize.Promise.reject(err); 
    }

           user.setDataValue('password_hash',hash);
    user.setDataValue('password_salt',salt);
   });

  });
 }
    },
    instanceMethods: {
 generateHash: function(password) {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null); 
 },
 validPassword: function(password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password); 
 }
    }
  });

  //User.associate = (models) => {
  //  User.hasMany(models.UserType, {
  //    foreignKey: 'userId',
  //    as: 'userTypes'
  //  });
  //};

  return User;
};
```

And here's the call:

```js
return db.User
   .create({
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name, 
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email, 
    password_hash: req.body.password 
   })
   .then(user => res.status(201).send(user))
   .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I use the crypto, included in node.js : https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

I have a function to create the hash :

```
function createHash(password, salt) {
  const generatedSalt = typeof salt !== 'undefined' ? salt : crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('base64');
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', generatedSalt);
  hmac.update(password);
  const hashedPassword = hmac.digest('hex');
  return {
    salt: generatedSalt,
    hash: hashedPassword
  };
}
```

And in my user model :

```
beforeCreate: (user, options, cb) => {
  const saltAndHash = createHash(user.password);
  user.salt = saltAndHash.salt;
  user.password = saltAndHash.hash;
  return cb(null, options);
}
```

I hope this will help you ;)